# How can I run multiple proxies on the same computer simultaneously each IP/Proxy on a specific app client in a sandboxed environment?

Tags: networking, proxy, sandbox, socks5, sandboxie

I have several running clients of the same app that I need to set a proxy for each client in a sandboxed environment. Also, it'd be better if it could be automated, as it's a daily changing Proxy IP.

I've tried Proxifier with Sandboxie plus but it's so hard to be automated and takes a ton of time to set up on a massive scale as the IP is changed daily so setting up each one of them daily is so inefficient.

Comment: Yes i'm using brightdata and iproyal for this

Comment: i need to use several ips at the same time, would this help?